# Evaluating the percentage of True for a unique value in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, validation

I have a data set with several colums of which I would like to evaluate 2 of them. One of the columns displays integers between 0 and 1 and the other gives the name of a brand. I would like to know how I could get the number of times the column 1 has a 1 for each unique value of the brand column.

Ex:

```
Sold out      Brand

1             Twinkies

1             kitkat

0             Twinkies

0             Nerds

0             Rice krispies 

0             Twinkies

1             snickers
```

and that the result could be:

Twinkies: 33% - 1/3

kitkat: 100% - 1/1

Nerds: 0% - 0/1

Rice krispies 0% - 0/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
g = df.groupby('Brand')
g['Sold out'].sum() / g['Brand'].size() * 100
```

Output:

```
Brand
Nerds         0.000000
Rice          0.000000
Twinkies     33.333333
kitkat      100.000000
snickers    100.000000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) - it is number of `1` values divided by counts:

```
s = df.groupby('Brand')['Sold out'].mean().mul(100)
print (s)
Brand
Nerds              0.000000
Rice krispies      0.000000
Twinkies          33.333333
kitkat           100.000000
snickers         100.000000
Name: Sold out, dtype: float64
```